# For loop with multiple lines is taking more time

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

using for loop in single lines:

```
%%time
y = [x*2 if x%2 != 0 else x+2 for x in range(10000000)]


CPU times: user 1.27 s, sys: 150 ms, total: 1.42 s
Wall time: 1.42 s
```

using for loop in multiple lines:

```
%%time
y =[]
for x in range(10000000):
    if x%2 != 0:
        y.append(x*2)
    else:
        y.append(x+2)
CPU times: user 2.45 s, sys: 198 ms, total: 2.65 s
Wall time: 2.65 s
```

Why second for loop is taking more time? Both are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's because appending to a list will cause this list to expand space many times. Reserve this required space at once will save expansion cost.

Try this:

```
y = [0] * 10000000
for x in range(10000000):
     if x % 2 != 0:
         y[x] = x*2
     else:
         y[x] = x+2
```

Comment: have you compared your solution to others time-wise? note `if x % 2 != 0:` => `if x % 2:`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this solution is slightly slower than the list comprehension one, but faster than the list append one. Open ipython and you can %%time them yourself.